# how do you remove the footer links?

Tags: magento-1.9, footer-links

How do you edit the default footer links that Magento applies? Orders and Returns, Search term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the links you mean are the following folder

```
\app\design\frontend\default\themeXXXX\
```

The Order and Return link is in **layout/sales.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
   <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
     <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

The Sitemap link you can find here:**layout/catalog.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
</reference>
```

The Search terms link you can find here: 
**layout/catalogsearch.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
        <label>Search Terms</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
        <title>Search Terms</title>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
        <label>Advanced Search</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The contacts link in:
**layout/contacts.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
</reference>
```

Just comment the ones out you want to remove. If you want to remove all of them and just add your static cms block "footer_links" then you will need to copy this file `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php` to your local files and comment the following piece of code out

```
$this->getLinks();
```

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: How it can be removed from local.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking the footer block. Go to CMS - Static blocks and search "footer". From there you should be able to edit the footer links.

Comment: yeah I've tried that non of the blocks link to the group of links I want to edit,

Comment: That is quite uncommon, are you using the default Magento theme? Can you add a screenshot with the links you want to remove?

Comment: Then you need to find this in your theme file.  Are you using Default theme?  If so it should be blank/default.  Go here: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml and see if that works for you.  The page directory listed will point you to your layout XML file and PHP (.phtml)